# restarting builds with travis ci api

Tags: travis-ci, travis-ci-api

I can restart builds via the CLI by doing `travis show branch -r user/project` to get the build # and then by doing `travis restart 1 -r user/project` (where 1 is the build).

My question is...  how can I do this via the [Travis CI v3 API](https://developer.travis-ci.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you first need to get the repository.id by doing `curl -L http://api.travis-ci.org/repos/username/project`

Then you can then get the various build #'ers by sending a GET request to https://api.travis-ci.org/repo/repository.id/builds (altho that'll return older builds as well, up to 25) and then you can restart by sending a POST request to https://api.travis-ci.org/build/build.id/restart with build.id={whatever the build.id is} as the POST data.

See https://developer.travis-ci.com/resource/builds and https://developer.travis-ci.com/resource/build#restart for more info.